# Is this sequence in $\mathcal{l}_1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $\{\lambda_i\}_{i=1}^\infty\subset \mathbb{R}^+$ be a nondecreasing sequence of positive real numbers,  such that $\lim_{i\to \infty} \lambda_i = \infty$.

Define $\theta \colon \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}^+$ as
$$
\theta(i) = \sup_{j\in \mathbb{N}} \frac{1}{(1+\lambda_j^2)^i}\lambda_j^2 i.
$$

I suspect (hope) that $\theta\in \mathcal{l}_1.$  Is this true?  I would appreciate any help or a counter example.  Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notice that for $i\geq 1$ one has $$\frac{\lambda_j^2i}{(1+\lambda_j^2)^i}< \frac{i}{(1+\lambda_j^2)^{i-1}}\leq \frac{i}{(1+\lambda_0^2)^{i-1}}$$
so $\theta(i)<\frac{i}{(1+\lambda_0^2)^{i-1}}$ and is therefore in $\mathcal{l}^1$.

Comment: You wrote that the sequence is in $\mathbb{R}^+$